# PayPal Cart Upload - Link to return to pay later if the user clicks away from PayPal

Tags: php, paypal

Using the PayPal cart upload and IPN system works great, what I am wondering now is if there is a way for the customer to return to the payment screen with the correct items in the cart if they were to close the PayPal window or just want come back to pay at another time, rather than right after the transaction.

I can't imagine that the situation would come up often, but it would be nice to be able to provide the customer a link in their original order confirmation that they could click and be served the same payment screen as when they click checkout.

Hopefully that makes sense, and hopefully someone has figured this out before!!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using your database. Keep their items in a cart, and generate a new "payment" accordingly.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense.  I am trying to keep things as simple as possible for a custom small paypal shopping cart site with less than 10 items.  As of now I am having the IPN response update the orders table directly.  I see what you are saying though and I will give that a try and create the necessary new tables.  I just was hoping that there would be a solution on the PayPal side, since I have the order ID in a custom field.